# Посчитать количество подряд идущих одинаковых записей SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

| Date | Time | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-07 | 11:00 | true |
| 2023-04-07 | 12:00 | true |
| 2023-04-07 | 13:00 | false |
| 2023-04-07 | 14:00 | false |
| 2023-04-07 | 15:00 | true |

Из такой таблицы нужно получить следующую:

| Date | Time | Check | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-07 | 11:00 | true | 1 |
| 2023-04-07 | 12:00 | true | 2 |
| 2023-04-07 | 13:00 | false | 1 |
| 2023-04-07 | 14:00 | false | 2 |
| 2023-04-07 | 15:00 | true | 1 |

Либо такую, т е максимальное количество идущих подряд одинаковых записей для каждого дня по колонке чек.

| Date | Check | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-07 | true | 2 |
| 2023-04-07 | false | 2 |

В стартовой таблице идёт сортировка по дате времени и чеку.
Если сделаю `ROW_NUMBERS() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE) AS Count`, получу в итоге просто 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 в 4й колонке.

Если `PARTITION BY DATE, Check`, то он отсортирует по дате, а потом по чеку, в итоге получу тоже не то, что нужно. Как сделать, чтобы сортировка была по дате и времени, но при этом подсчет одинаковых подряд записей шёл по дате и чеку?

Answer (score 2):

```
select date, time, "Check", row_number() over(partition by date, grp order by time) "Count"
  from (
    select date, time, "Check", sum(grp) over(partition by date order by time) grp
      from (
        select *, case "Check" when lag("Check") over(partition by date order by time, "Check") then 0 else 1 end grp
          from tab
      ) x
  ) y
```

Сначала сравниваем подряд идущие Check в пределах группы по дате и сортировки по времени, при несовпадении даем 1, иначе 0. Так мы "размечаем" начало каждой интересующей нас на самом деле группы. На втором шаге суммируем эту разметку и получаем одинаковые номера групп у идущих подряд одинаковых значений. Далее нам остается только пронумеровать записи в этих, вновь полученных группах.